# How do I apply my php code to a bootstrap code?

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display something from my database on a bootstrap bar and I have no idea how to combine or implement the two. Ive made my bootstrap html's file a .php, was that the correct thing to do? Here's my code (ignore the filler words)

```
<ul class="nav nav-list well">

        <li class="nav-header"></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HIT INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Linky link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">ANOTHER HIT INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ANOTHER LINKY LINK</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">YET ANOTHER HIT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AAAAAnd another link</a></li>

    </ul>
```

and this is the php i want to include (the code to making what i want to display is in the file)

```
<?php include 'one.php'; ?>
```

where "linky link" is, i want to display this but it didnt seem to  work when i put that php right there. Another thing i want to do is when a link from the database gets displayed, it displays as a bootstrap button. i tried and am just not sure how to implement php code in my bootstrap code.

```
Print " <td>".$row['link'] . "</td></tr> ";
```

How would i add this bootstrap code to that so when a link from my database gets displayed, it gets displayed as this button

```
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><i class="icon-heart icon-white"></i>Do this HIT!</a>
```

Comment: Are you querying anything? What's in one.php? What is it should the button do? Load another page? Return results of a query?

Comment: yes, in the one.php is where im querying and connecting to the database. the result of one of the rows (the 'link') row is what i want to display as the button. not load another page or anything like that. instead of ppl seeing a link, they will see this button. the button will take them to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems right to me except to your "`<td>` and `<tr>`" tag. You're not using it right.
Try this approach

In one.php

```
<?php 

$links = array( 0 => array("url"=>"http://google.com","text"=>"Google") );

?>
```

In Menu

```
<?php include('one.php')?>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu one</a></li>
<?php foreach( $links as $link){ ?>
<li><a href="<?php print $link['url']?>"><?php print $link['text']?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: you're better off using `foreach():` and `endforeach;` if they are in seperate php code blocks. Otherwise it's harder to read. Also - consistent whitespace helps (in the php file - rendered output doesn't matter).

Comment: Thank you very much, ROMMEL. That showed me how to go about doing it.

Comment: @AD7six thanks for your input. I am using notepad++ that's why it is easier for me to use `{}` but i will consider your comment. Thanks